# How to export multiple ranges in singe HTML using Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen solutions on exporting range to .html using vba in Excel, but when I try to use any of those solutions to export a range that is created by UNION(rng1, rng2) I get thrown an error:

> Runtime error '1004': This action won't work on multiple selections

Now the code that throws this works fine if I have single range passed as argument, but throws this error when passing combined range

```
Public Function PublishPlan(rngToPublish As Range, location As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    rngToPublish.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
       .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
       .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
       .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
       .Cells(1).Select
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       On Error Resume Next
       .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
       .DrawingObjects.Delete
       On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=location, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(location).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    PublishPlan = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    PublishPlan = Replace(PublishPlan, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Is it possible to have a function that can combine one, two or more ranges into a single .html file by adding them one bellow the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined ranges have multiple areas so loop through them pasting each below the previous.

```vb
    Dim rng As Range, r As Long
    r = 1

    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)

        For Each rng In rngToPublish.Areas
            rng.Copy
            .Cells(r, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .Cells(r, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
            .Cells(r, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
            r = r + rng.Rows.Count
        Next
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With
```

Comment: I am marking this as solution because it does work. However, I did not know that it is relevant to mention in my question that the ranges are not the same size, they have different number of columns. When I run this with the same size ranges it just works BUT if the ranges are with different number of columns i do get an error "To do this, all the merged cells need to be the same size". Can I overcome this? Maybe dynamically add empty cells to the range that is smaller??

Comment: @al1len It should work with different size ranges, I tested it with `Call PublishPlan(Range("A1:C10,B15:F20"), "c:\temp\plan.html")`. Are there merged cells within the ranges you are selecting ?

Comment: @ CDP1802, there are no merged cells, I've tried calling it with 2 params as PublishPlan(Sheets("main").Range("range1"), Sheets("main").Range("range2"), location) and also PublishPlan(range, location) where range is Sheets("main").Range("range1, range2)- in both cases fails. Either on the line where it says .Cells(r, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False OR the previous error from above in the question

Comment: @al1len I thought you were using `Call PublishPlan(Union(Range("range1"), Range("range2")), location)`

Comment: tried that also, still highlights the .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False

Comment: @al1len Add `debug.print rngToPublish.address` to your code and post the result so I can reproduce it.

Comment: $B$3:$X$24,$B$25:$U$32

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236513/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-al1en).